# jquery to check a textarea for a particular word and shows a text input (and popover) asking for user input before submitting form

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, textarea, popover

I have this html page below:

```html
<form name="form1" action="hhhhh.php">
  <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="8">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <textarea name="message" id="wysiwygeditor" placeholder="enter message here..."></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>second content</td>
      <td>third content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="phrase" id="phrase" placeholder="your desired password">
      </td>
      <td>fifth content</td>
      <td>sixth content</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

<input type="submit" name="submit2" id="submit2" value="Send Message">
```

The above page is used for registration of a user manually,
Desired behaviour:

1. Page loads and the input[type='text'] field is hidden by default
2. A user begins to type into the textarea Box
3. If the word "register" is detected, the input[type='text'] becomes visible and the submit button becomes unclickeable. A popover then appears by the right of the input[type='text'] field displaying a message for user to input his desired username and password.
4. Once any word/character/string/number or anything is entered into that now visble input[type='text'], the submit button becomes clickeble once more.

   5. Now, user can finally proceed to submit this form.

**NOTE: Please I want this validation to be programmed using jQuery Only.** Not PHP, not vanilla javascript because I want it to be cross-browser compactible.

My attempts so far with jQuery is shown below:

```js
$("#submit2").on('click', function(el) {
  if ($('#wysiwygeditor').val().indexOf('register') > -1) {
    if (!$('#phrase').val()) {
      $('#phrase').popover({
        title: 'Warning!',
        content: 'Value can not be empty. What is your desired username for registration?',
        placement: 'right'
      }).popover('show');
      el.preventDefault();
      return false;
    } else {
      $('#phrase').popover('destroy');
      return true;
    }
  } else {
    $('#phrase').popover('destroy');
  }
  return true;
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to display and hide the text-box depending on the value of your text-area so you should add your code to an event related to text-area not to the submit button, the same for enabling or disabling submit button it depends on typing inside the text-box.

so here is one solution you can do

```
$("#msg").on('keyup', function() {
    if($(this).val().indexOf("register") > -1){
        $('#phrase').css('display','block');
        $('#submit2').prop('disabled', true);            
        //You can show your popver code here

    }
    else{
        $('#phrase').css('display','none');
        $('#submit2').prop('disabled', false);
        //You hide your popover code here
    }
});
$('#phrase').on('keyup', function() {
    if($(this).val() != '')
        $('#submit2').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Here is working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0gjooqh2/) for you

Note*: i don't know which popover you are using and i'm not sure if it is working in the way you want, so if you need help in it please be more spicific.